# How to make some labels BOLD using Expression Builder QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling

I am using QGIS 2.14 and I am trying to make some of my labels bold to stand out. I'm not sure how to do this using the expression builder. I know this is wrong and I was wondering if someone could let me know how to correct it:

```
CASE WHEN
"Style" like '%2016%' then  Bold
ELSE Normal
END
```

*"Style" is my layer of points, I need the 2016 labels in **bold**.*

My only solution I have at the moment is making a 'Bold' column in my attribute table and using this field to select features to be bold. I think this clutters up my attribute table and different maps require different labels bold.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your **Label** settings interface, click the *Data defined overide* button for the bold option:

[image: Label bold setting]

Then use an expression like:

```
CASE WHEN "Style" LIKE '%2016%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

The input for this setting is boolean (i.e. 1 or 0).